# How do I use StringReplace to replace repeated characters?

Tags: programming, string-manipulation

Suppose I have

```
 str = "dededekmkmkmvkfjdedemkvmlvdedekfmmdedededemkmkde"
```

And I want to replace the repeated "de"s to one and produce (in a real example, the "de"s are actually "\n"s):

```
 str = "dekmkmkmvkfjdemkvmlvdekfmmdemkmkde"
```

I try

```
  StringReplace[str, "dede" -> "de"]
```

but only one duplicate "de" is removed, and something like

```
 StringReplace[str, {"dede" -> "de","dede" -> "de,"dede" -> "de}]
```

makes no difference.

What should I do? `Nest[StringReplace[#, "dede" -> "de"] &, str, 100]` is a little ugly and unnatural...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a [repeated pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RepeatedPatterns.html) so you can use the `..` placeholder, (**edit** I just realized this is exactly what Kuba was saying in his comment)

```
StringReplace[str, "de" .. -> "de"]
% == "dekmkmkmvkfjdemkvmlvdekfmmdemkmkde"
(* "dekmkmkmvkfjdemkvmlvdekfmmdemkmkde" *)
(* True *)
```

@J.M. suggests [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html),

```
StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(de)+"] -> "de"]
(* "dekmkmkmvkfjdemkvmlvdekfmmdemkmkde" *)
```

You can go old-school and use a `While` loop,

```
While[
  StringContainsQ[str, "dede"],
  str = StringReplace[str, "dede" -> "de"];
  ];
str
(* "dekmkmkmvkfjdemkvmlvdekfmmdemkmkde" *)
```

OP's idea of using `Nest` can be a made little more elegant by using `NestWhile`,

```
NestWhile[StringReplace[#, "dede" -> "de"] &, str, 
 StringContainsQ["dede"]]
(* "dekmkmkmvkfjdemkvmlvdekfmmdemkmkde" *)
```

Comment: Regex: `StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(de)+"] -> "de"]`